# Scandipwa-base_ssl-term Error In Magento 2

Tags: docker, progressive-web-apps, magento-2.3

In my Magento 2.3 project, I'm trying to add the [ScandiPWA](https://scandipwa.com/) base theme. After running the `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.local.yml -f docker-compose.ssl.yml up -d` command, I get these below.

> Recreating 971fc3682291_scandipwa-base_ssl-term_1_b5cb8a68c213 ... error

> ERROR: for 971fc3682291_scandipwa-base_ssl-term_1_b5cb8a68c213  Cannot
> start service ssl-term: driver failed programming external
> connectivity on endpoint scandipwa-base_ssl-term_1_b5cb8a68c213
> (2d533c2c4d61452bbf1a5a2b9471d988d4a98b2f10e2f0ba57cbb1c60dbc6412):
> Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address
> already in use

> ERROR: for ssl-term  Cannot start service ssl-term: driver failed
> programming external connectivity on endpoint
> scandipwa-base_ssl-term_1_b5cb8a68c213
> (2d533c2c4d61452bbf1a5a2b9471d988d4a98b2f10e2f0ba57cbb1c60dbc6412):
> Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address
> already in use ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the
> project.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I'm already using the port 80!!

Change the default port in the **`docker-compose.yml`**